# Make Dropdown Box Like Google

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2C4Q.png

Hello, I have this problem,

How to make dropdown box like google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve that with CSS.

set `<ul>` to

```
list-style-type: none;
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
```

you may want to format `<li>` items too.

Comment: <div class="tab-content">
         <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_15_1">
          <form action="#">
           <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-cont"> 
             <input id="artist" type="text" placeholder="Search1..." class="form-control"/>
            </div>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn green-haze">
            Search &nbsp; <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>
            </button>
            </span>
           </div>
          </form>
          </div>